# how to get tuple in jpql using params

Tags: jpa, jpql

Now I am using JPA to access database. I want to get the comments in the specific courses and specific lessons, so the sql would like this:

```
select * from comment where (commentType, commentId) in (("course", "1"), ("lesson", 2))
```

I use annotation @Query like this:

```
@Query("select c from Comment c where (c.commentType, c.commentId) in :attaches")
Page<Comment> findByAttachIn(@Param("attaches") List<String[]> attaches, Pageable pageable);
```

But finally I got the sql like this:

```
select * from comment where (commentType, commentId) in (?)
```

JPA can not translate the array from jql to sql. What shall I do?

Comment: IIRC, tuples need to have the same number of "columns" on both sides; you have 2 on the left but only on the right.

Comment: @Param("attaches") List<String[]> attaches, each String[] have 2 element. The problem is JPA just treat String[] as one column. Actually it is 2.

Comment: Split it to two lists, one for each column?

Comment: select * from comment where (commentType, commentId) in (("course", "1"), ("lesson", 2))

Comment: I want to get sql like this. So the tuple can not split. Or I can do it by other sql?

Answer (score 1):

An `IN` expression allows only a single-valued path expressions, so you can't do `(commentType, commentId) in` in a JPQL query.

Comment: so if i want to implement the feature, is there any other way?

Comment: Well, since you are using ID's, why not just use `where id in :idList` ?

Comment: select * from comment where (commentType, commentId) in (("course", "1"), ("lesson", 2)). commentType is one of the condition. id is not enough...

Comment: commentType is the field for comment with id ?, yes? Selecting by id will only yield a specific entity, so it doesn't matter whether or not you include the commentType in the where clause.

Comment: commentId is not the primary key for comment, the id is... commentId is the foreign key in table course or lesson or others.

Answer (score -1):

JPQL BNF documentation is very clear for the IN part

```
in_expression ::= {state_field_path_expression | type_discriminator} [NOT] IN { ( in_item {, in_item}* ) | (subquery) | collection_valued_input_parameter } 
in_item ::= literal | single_valued_input_parameter
```

Consequently it can be concluded that you can't do that in JPQL. What you can do is do it manually in the WHERE clause ...

```
... WHERE (commentType = :type1 AND commentId = :id1) OR 
          (commentType = :type2 AND commentId = :id2) OR 
          ...
```

long winded, but gets the answer, and complies with JPQL BNF notation. How you convert standard JPQL into some Spring syntax is left as an exercise to those familiar with that non-standard part

Comment: I still do not know how to do... I am not sure home many types will be. And ... centainly not suport in code. Can you give me the Java code

Comment: Your question asks how to do this in JPQL, and this answers that question (since the above syntax is JPQL). How you get Spring Data to handle dynamic queries is a separate question